# Out-File writes an empty file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am on a system that is on PowerShell v2.

I have a script that deletes old backups files. I would like to save the results of the script, as I see it on the on screen to be written to a file so that I can review what all files were deleted.

I read that `Write-Host` output that I see on the screen cannot be redirected to a file so I tried using the `Write-Output` as well, but can get the results to be written to the file. The file get created, but it's empty.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Here is the code:

```
$Stamp1 = Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyy_hhmmss"
$File= "E:\SSBackups\PS_Delete_Script_logs\Delete_Backup_Results_$Stamp1.txt"
$ReadFile = Get-Content C:\Users\MSA050415\Desktop\List.txt
foreach ($Folder in $ReadFile) {
    #Write-Host "Folder currently being worked on: $Folder" -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Output "Folder currently being worked on: $Folder"
    $Path ="E:\SSBackups\Database_Backups\$Folder"
    #Write-Host "The Path is set to $Path" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Output "The Path is set to $Path"
    Get-ChildItem $Path |
        Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt "4/17/2018 12:15:00 AM"} |
        Remove-Item -Verbose |
        Out-File $File
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verbose output is written to the [verbose output stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/), which cannot be redirected in PowerShell v2. That feature was added in PowerShell v3.

You should be able to record a transcript, though:

```
Start-Transcript $File -Append
Get-ChildItem $Path |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt "4/17/2018 12:15:00 AM"} |
    Remove-Item -Verbose
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This worked. It's because I have V2.0 on this machine which makes things really outdated. So, If were to not use -VERBOSE, could I then use Out-File ?

Comment: @Amir That would write regular output to the output file, but without the `-Verbose` parameter `Remove-Item` wouldn't be showing information about what it's deleting in the first place, so the output file would still remain empty.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers Thank you Sir! makes sense. I am trying to learn this so that one day I want to answer others questions and help others. It would feel just right!!!